# If $\mu$ is atomic and $\mu(A)=0$ then $A=\emptyset$?

Tags: measure-theory

In my research I have the following property:

If $\mu(A_x)=\mu(\{x\})$, then either $A_x=\{x\}$ or $\mu(A_x)=0$.

We know that if compact and Hausdorff space $X$  contains no perfect subsets there is no non-atomic Borel measure on $X$.

Can I say that if compact and Hausdorff space $X$  contains no perfect subsets 
 and $\mu(A_x)=\mu(\{x\})$, then  $A_x=\{x\}$?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven. Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space without perfect subset . Let for $x\in X$ and $x\in A_x\subseteq X$, if $\mu(A_x)= \mu(\{x\})$, then either $A_x=\{x\}$  or $\mu(A_x)=0$. Can I say that $\mu(A_x)=0$ can not be happen?

Comment: It can happen, take the zero measure.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, But in my research I suppose that $\mu$ is non-zero measure.

Comment: Take two compact sets and take on one set a dirac measure and on the other one you take the zero measure. Then you still don't get what you claim.

Answer (score 3):

The objection you give to Severin Schraven's comment isn't a particularly good one since it misses the idea of the comment. The point is that there can be regions of zero measure so that $\mu(A) = \mu(\{x\}) > 0$ but $A = \{x\} \cup B$ where $\mu(B) = 0$.

For a concrete example, consider $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. This is compact, Hausdorff and contains no perfect subsets since every point is isolated. Let $\mu(\{0\}) = 1, \mu(\{1\}) = 0$. Then for $A = \{0,1\}$, $\mu(A) = \mu(\{0\}) > 0$ but $A \neq \{0\}$.

Comment: +1, nicely phrased.